# Is it possible to use jQuery events on server-side node.js?

Tags: node.js

This not a very 'correct' way to use node.js, but i have some complex jQuery client-side code that is very easy to test via node.js: i just run 'node sometest.js' and tests are executed command-line without a need for a browser. Very handy.

But i can't execute my code that use jQuery events in node.js, since jQuery events are based on `document` object that is browser-specific and don't have any relationships with node.js on server side:

```
$( document ).bind( 'myevent', function( e, a ) { console.log( a ); } );
$( document ).trigger( 'myevent', [ 'foo' ] );
```

Is there some easy way to use jQuery events on node.js, or is it based on technologies completely alien to server side?

Comment: Node has an events implementation (called [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html)). It is not API-compatible with jQuery so I suggest you look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, `process` can be used in `jQuery` in some cases instead of `document` or `window`. Works with events.